# How to add custom layout to spinner items

Tags: android, android-spinner

I made one application that using the spinner in it. in my application client wants the specific design (Means not a option button but i have to show the checkbox instead )
so i need to inflate some custom layout .xml file that having the checkbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to add the custom layout to Spinner items:

1. In Main Layout you have the main Layout find that object
2. then create the layout xml file that you want to in spinner items
3. Use following code to inflate the layout xml

-

```
main_ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.cities_big_linear);
LayoutInflater linflater = getLayoutInflater();

for(int i=0;i<cities.length;i++)
{
        CustomView = null;
        CustomView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_row, null);
         CustomView.setId(i);
        TextView tv = (TextView)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.txt_text);
        tv.setText(cities[i].toString());
        main_ll.addView(CustomView);
}
```

Comment: cities is my array that having the List of the Cities.

Comment: it's spinner items array list

Answer (score 0):

Create custom adapter by extending any adapter like baseAdapter, CursorAdapter ect .

set custom Layout through getView

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue by using

```
yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner );
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,yourArraylistToBeLoad);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: But i want custom layout, where i can add a checkbox imageview and radio button